# Bind data to a control inside the headertemplate of a repeater

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to bind data to a label control inside the headertemplate. I have tried itemdataboud but the value is not displayed. When I put the control inside the itemtemplate then the value is displayed. Why can't I bind to a control inside the headertemplate?

```
<HeaderTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTitle"></asp:Label>
</HeaderTemplate>
```

I have used this as well: `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title")%>` but I cannot get it to work.

Help please